# dynamically add hyperlink or button to open local file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make a button or hyperlink to open local html file. I have tried everything but none of them are not working. have tried to use LinkButton, Button and Hyperlink. Below is the code what I have tried.

```
byte[] buffer = (byte[])data.GetValue(i);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\test.html", buffer);
//LinkButton sysInfo = new LinkButton();
//sysInfo.Text = "Please click to see more info";
//sysInfo.CommandName = "ID";
//sysInfo.CommandArgument = id.ToString();
//sysInfo.Command += new CommandEventHandler(sysInfo_Click);
//sysInfo.Click += new EventHandler(this.sysInfo_Click);

HyperLink link = new HyperLink();

link.Target = "_blank";
link.Text = "Please click to see more information";
link.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('" + ResolveUrl("file:///c:/test.html") + "');");
link.NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl("file:///c:/test.html");
fieldCl.Controls.Add(link);
//sysInfo.Click += new EventHandler(sysInfo_Click);
//sysInfo.CommandName = "ID";
//sysInfo.CommandArgument = id.ToString();
//sysInfo.Command += new CommandEventHandler(sysInfo_Click);
```

What I was trying to do is there are bytes for html in sql server and retrieve the bytes to create file on C: local. Then I want to open the local html file on new window.

It seems ok to retrieve bytes and create a file. But when I used the hyperlink, it does not do anything. I heard that it won't allow me to open the local file. So I have tried to use the button instead but when I used a button and create Click event, it didnt even go into the Click event.

If there is anyway to just open the file without saving, that would be great but if can't, that's fine.

Comment: Do u want to open a popup window or to download the HTML file?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Hi Chamara I just would like to open a popup window with a html file saved on sql server. I saved html file as a binary in sql and trying to open it. Is there any way without saving? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would just get your link into a string.  It would just need to be: `c:\\test.html`

Once you get your link into a string I would try: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(link);`

If that is not working, I would place a break in your code and grab the content of the string - paste that into your address bar and see what happens.

Comment: Hi there Thanks for your answer. Where do you want me to put Process.Start? using Hyperlink or button?? I cannot use hyperlink.NavigateUrl = Process.Start(); as it only allow to put string. I have used break point and tried that but still not working. Any other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start only works with windows forms applications and in ASP.NET only in local machine.it want work once you publish the application to the server.